# Implementing nested If-cycles in a winform

Tags: c#, winforms, nested

For example I have a nested if-cycle in console like

```
if (answer == "one")
{
    Console.WriteLine("one or two?");
    string answer = Console.ReadLine();

    if (answer == "one")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("pressed1");
    }
    else 
        Console.WriteLine("pressed2")
    //....and so on
}
```

Everything works fine.
But if I try to do the same in winform, it turns out that by pressing Button1 **I get all the nested results marked as "btn1".So I am getting "pressed 1 pressed 1"**. How can I make my program stop the same way it stops in console with Console.ReadLine()?

```
if (btn.Name == "btn1")
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText("Pressed1");
    if (btn.Name == "btn1")
    {
        richTextBox1.AppendText("pressed1");
    }
    else (btn.Name == "btn2")
    {
        richTextBox1.AppendText("pressed2");
    }
```

Comment: Your best bet is an internal state. Each time the button is pressed, log (internally) when and what order it was pressed in.

Comment: so if your answer was one, then it would output "one or two?" "pressed1", and in winforms you should get "Pressed1" "Pressed1"? If thats true I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. Your first if() statement is checking if the button is 'btn1' and then your nested if() statement is checking again. The 'else (btn.Name=="btn2")' will never be true in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code fragment isn't full, but it's easy to speculate what the confusion is.

Basically, your console application is being processed in a sequential order, with certain blocking calls where input is injected into the flow.

On your WinForm application on the other hand, flow is event based. There is no predetermined sequence of events, and no blocking calls.

Your console code inspects the value of the `answer` variable in the outer `if` and then waits for a new input from the user for further processing. Your WinForm code inspects `btn.Name`, appends some text to a text box, and then ***immediately*** moves on to the next `if` statement. If you want to stop this sequence, `return` from your event handler, and continue your flow in a different event handler.

***A note for potential -1's:*** Yes, I know a console application can be event based, doesn't have to be sequential in nature and so on. This answer is supposed to help the OP understand the logic & problem.

Comment: Thank you, Amit. I understand much clearer what the problem is. Still don't see how to make a block call to make a program wait for a next button pressing.

Comment: You can't, and it's not the way event based process work. You need to split your logic to multiple parts that perform their "magic" whenever the relevant event is triggered. For example - Have 2 buttons. Clicking the 1st button sets a text field with the 1st value, and clicking the 2nd sets the 2nd value.